# Put arrow pointed to the left on thead or th

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to fetch data and put it into a table each. In between the `<thead><th></th></thead>` is the username, and the remaining rows is for additional data. What I want to achieve is to have a pointed-like arrow to the left, pointing in the corresponding user's picture.

Here's a sample screen shot:
[image]

I want to have a point that looks like this, highlighted in red box:

[image]

I'm using bootstrap for the CSS.
Here's the part of the code that I'm trying to configure:

```
echo "<div class='row'>";
   echo "<div class='col-md-1'><img src='images/propic/$fimg' class='img-circle' width='50' height='50'></div>";
   echo "<div class='col-md-11'>";
     echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'><thead class='right'><th class='right'>".$fname."</th></thead>";
     echo "<tr><td>".$ftaskdesc."</td></tr></table>";
   echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do folowing:

```
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #88b7d5;
    border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-right-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-right-color: #c2e1f5;
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-top: -36px;
}
```

Check this out http://cssarrowplease.com/